# Soup.find and findAll unable to find table elements on hockey-reference.com

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just a beginner at webscraping and python in general so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, but I can't figure out I'm unable to find any of the table elements on https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2018.html.

My initial thought was that this was a result of the whole div being commented out, so following some advice I found on here in another similar post, I replaced the comment characters and confirmed that they were removed when I saved the soup.text to a text file and searched. I was still unable to find any tables however.

In trying to search a little further I took the ID out of my .find and did a findAll and still table was coming up empty.

Here's the code I was trying to use, any advice is much appreciated!

```
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")

url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2018.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(comm.sub("", html))
table = soup.find('table', id="stats")
```

When searching for all of the table elements I was using

```
table = soup.findAll('table')
```

I'm also aware that there is a csv version on the site, I was just eager to practice.

Answer (score 0):

Give a parser along with your markup, for example `BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')` . Try the below code

```
url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2018.html'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('table')
```